# Package dependency SSIS

Tags: ssis

Developers constantly ask for changes to table structures (column name, PK, FK) in SQL Server.

I need to know which packages of the SSIS project should be changed if any database table is changed.

There are more than 100 packages I can't do it manually, because it will take too long.

Any suggestion?
Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you'd benefit from creating a data lineage or mapping document.

Comment: Could you give me more details?, please